# How to fetch/delete facebook comment using graph api

Tags: php, facebook

Scenario - I am tring to display list of comment posted by user on my website admin area and want to delete (abuse/spam/etc) comments

I have tried to execute https://graph.facebook.com/COMMENT_ID/?method=delete&access_token=|

Where COMMENT_ID = 765892

Still it is not working.

Can you please help

Comment: Did you add a valid access token? What was the response from Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it from your browser easily, as mentioned in the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/), you need to use a DELETE http request to delete it. Try using the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to do the same request, but using DELETE in the left hand method drop down.

Also, make sure that the access token you are using has `read_stream` extended permission.

Comment: I have already sent the http post request to graph api but no success.

Comment: You don't send a http POST request, you need to send a http DELETE request, they are different types of http requests!